# A word that describes a person that falsely claims to be a part of a group and purposefully behaves in such a way as to garner disdain for that group

Tags: single-word-requests

The context is to describe groups such as "Stop Oil" that claim to be environmentalists, but behave in such a way to garner disdain of environmentalists (like blocking traffic which forces cars to idle and pollute MORE while also pissing off the very people they should be trying to win over), and in turn, their cause.

Comment: I doubt if these people are provocateurs though. Some people think drastic measures are required. That you are writing here about them in such a way, implies they're getting the attention they want. I don't think they care if people like them, they want actions taken, whether people support the actions or not. Take for example people throwing paint on fur coats. Do they care if they change their minds about fur coats and support their cause? No, they just want them to stop wearing them.

Comment: I think the term to describe them would be 'people engaged in direct action', or 'activists', if there is not a more precise term for them.

Comment: The term for that sort of activity online is "moby" but that applies only to posting.

Comment: @user14094230 It would be very unsuccessful direct action and activisits. Earth Liberation Front or Earth First! are real examples of direct action. Gluing oneself to cultural artifacts does nothing for the environment and gives environmentalists a bad reputation. You may disagree with my example, but the words you've supplied do not have the meaning of my query.

Comment: Angering people is a normal part of direct action for all of them. Conspiracy people don't garner much support either. Single issue movements have worked. Fur coats did go out of style for the most part. Maybe they have outreach if one doubts their motives. They don't exactly hide who they are. Provocateurs are usually a few individuals. I've never heard of a whole movement being a totally fake front.

Comment: @user14094230: OP's focus is the disingenuous nature of the action, which your (first) comment glosses over. Note that we're not trying to establish if OP is correctly judging a particular group's intentions, but rather what the name for such a group or people would be _if these were indeed their intentions_.

Comment: Yes, I put that in an answer, twas moi

Comment: Your title and your example are not coherent: environmentalists stopping cars might be accused of being responsible for pollution and thus their action  be detrimental to their group's reputation, but they certainly do no dissociate themselves from the environmentalist movement.

Comment: @Flater: Where is the reference to disingenuousness? I missed it. I read the question as being about people who use tactics that alienate potential supporters of the broader movement, not because that is their goal (as might be the case when people are "planted" in a group by industry interests with the intention of discrediting the group) but because they believe  those tactics will achieve results.

Comment: See also **false flag**

Comment: @TimR the title says "falsely claims" which suggests disingenuousness to me. Although it's possible the OP changed their mind midway through, as it seems to be a very ill-thought-out rant.

Comment: @StuartF After reading the body of the question I figured "falsely" was intended to mean "wrongly" or "mistakenly" rather than "untruly".

Comment: @TimR OP says they "claim to be" environmentalists, which suggests to me that what they say is not what is actually true.

Comment: @flater: and yet OP says they are alienating "the very people they should be trying to win over". So I understood "claim" there to mean not that they're *posing* as environmentalists, but as a recrimination, to the effect that they're being very poor environmentalists. As in "You claim to be pro-environment, and yet you hire   landscaping companies that work with 2-stroke engines".

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 2):

[Provocateur](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provocateur) or [Agent Provocateur](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/agent%20provocateur) I think these would be the best fit. Other options are infiltrator, plant or mole, but they are more meant for spying. Plant I think is the next closest though.

-- one employed to associate with suspected persons and by pretending sympathy with their aims to incite them to some incriminating action

Comment: Good answer, but please add an appropriate dictionary definition.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person is **subversive**, or a subversive:

> *subversive* [adjective]
>
> 1: secretly trying to ruin or destroy a government, political system,
> etc ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subversive) includes 'organisation').
>
> subversive groups/activities
>
> - The government blamed a subversive organization for the riots.
>
> 2: criticizing something in a clever and indirect way in order to make
> it weaker or less effective
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subversion) has for *subversion* 'especially: a systematic attempt to overthrow or undermine a government or political system [etc] by persons working secretly from within')
>
> ..........
>
> *subversive* [noun], plural subversives [count]
>
> - *The government claims that the riots were incited by subversives*.

[[Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/subversive)]

Answer (score -2):

Perfect match is **Pseudo-Environmentalists** . . .

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pseudoenvironmentalist :

> false environmentalists.
> falsely promoting environmentalist goals.

Close match is **Hypocrite** . . .

> https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hypocrite :

> those who practice hypocrisy, who pretend to hold beliefs, or whose actions are not consistent with their claimed beliefs.
> pretenders , deceivers

Comment: OP's person is not a pretender, but is willing to use tactics that, OP says, are bound to alienate people who might be enlisted as supporters of the wider movement.